# How to run the PowerShell cmdlet "Disable-ADSyncExportDeletionThreshold"?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I want to delete Office 365 users from Active Directory PowerShell in Windows Server 2008 (x64)

There is a treshold so you can't delete more than 500 users.

Microsoft has a documentation to prevent accidetal deletes and it says "just run Disable-ADSyncExportDeletionThreshold" command and it's OK.

But I have a problem. When I try to disable treshold, PowerShell says:

```
    The term 'Disable-ADSyncExportDeletionThreshold' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try aga
in.
At line:1 char:38
+ Disable-ADSyncExportDeletionThreshold <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Disable-ADSyncExportDeletionThreshold:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Also I tried to import "ADSync" but module couldn't loaded.

Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above answer is great.

I would suggest that you disable it temporarily and enable it afterwards as it's enabled by default to prevent lots of deletions to be exported to Azure AD.  This helps to prevent from deleting accidentally.

Import module first:

[image]

If all the deletes are desired, then do the following:

1. To temporarily disable this protection and let those deletes go through, run the PowerShell cmdlet:

> Disable-ADSyncExportDeletionThreshold

.
 2. Provide an Azure AD Global Administrator account and password.

[image]
 3. With the Azure Active Directory Connector still selected, select the action Run and select Export.
[image]
 4. To re-enable the protection, run the PowerShell cmdlet:

> Enable-ADSyncExportDeletionThreshold

.
[image]

Comment: Just want to check if this helped or not:)

Comment: Thank you. 

This solution is useful. We solved our problem.

As you said, we import **adsync** module and disable **threshold.**

Before, we tried to do this on AD Server. 

Now, Azure Server Powershell helped us to disable treshold. :)

Thank you again.

Comment: Glad that this helped your issue. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

`Disable-ADSyncExportDeletionThreshold` is a commandlet for AAD Connect, you have to have AADConnect module installed and imported for it to work. Try `Import-Module “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\Bin\ADSync\ADSync.psd1”` if its not there, install it.

Also, take a look [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2014/10/01/how-to-run-manual-dirsync-azure-active-directory-sync-updates/).